# How can I change a Dagger module's injections by gradle flavor?

Tags: android, gradle, dagger

I have an Android/gradle project with two flavors that uses Dagger. These flavors have several activities in common, but each flavor has a couple of activities that are unique to the flavor. So, for one flavor:

```
@Module(injects = {
        CommonActivity1.class,
        CommonActivity2.class,
        Flavor1Activity.class,
})
public class MyModule { ... }
```

And for the other:

```
@Module(injects = {
        CommonActivity1.class,
        CommonActivity2.class,
        Flavor2Activity.class,
})
public class MyModule { ... }
```

The modules are identical except for the classes they inject. I'm currently just copying code between the two MyModule.java files, which are placed in the appropriate per-flavor directory.

I'd like to find a solution that avoids copy/pasted code between two identical modules, and ideally prevents needing to specify the common activities twice

I don't care whether the solution is in Java or Gradle. If there's a way to generate the annotation in Gradle, that's fine. If there's a way to refactor the injects list in Java, that's fine too. I'm also open to ideas for reorganizing my approach to Dagger to avoid the problem entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution here is addsTo.

If the content of the modules are the same then include the basic module implementation in your default source directory. Then in each of the flavour implementations create your flavour specific modules.

Use `addsTo = BaseModule.class` in your module annotations.

Using this method you only need to define the annotations in the module and can reuse the base implementation.

You end up with something like this

```
@Module (
        library = true
        , complete = false
)
public class BaseModule {}


@Module (
        library = true
        , complete = false
        , addsTo = BaseModule.class
        , injects = { ... }
)
public class FlavourOneModule {}

@Module (
        library = true
        , complete = false
        , addsTo = BaseModule.class
        , injects = { ... }
)
public class FlavourTwoModule {}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. The only alteration I made was to remove the library and complete flags from the per-flavor modules. Thanks!